# Multiple AMQ9209 and AMQ9208 errors in QMGR logs. But client connection is not interrupted

Tags: mq

As a MQ admin I come across AMQ9209 and AMQ9208 errors number of times but application does not report any connection issue with MQ qmgr most of the times. In that case these errors doens't make any sense.(May be application is using auto reconnect option).
I am aware of the causes from mq server side. But I want to know if there is anything that can be changed in application code to get rid of these tcp/ip errors.
Thanks.

Comment: What version of MQ is the queue manger running under?   What is the `SVRCONN`'s `HBINT`,  `DISCINT`, and `SHARECNV` set to?